# React props is undefiend

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Can't find an explanation for this.
In "componentdidmout" function I log to console this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
console.log(this);
console.log(this.props);
console.log(this.props[0]);
await this.getComments(this.props.product_id);
```

}

and that's the result
[console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taFNR.jpg)

Comment: I think your props type is object not an array.

Comment: Actually it is... and moreover it doesn’t matter because I also can’t reach this.props.